# Delphi - 'Invalid argument to date encode', because Value['Expires']=-1

Tags: delphi, http-headers, indy

I've been working with a application using delphi where the application needs to connect with a url like a "example.example.ex".

When I call the function `IdHTTP1.Post`, an error occurs in the date enconding process.

What happens is that, when the application get some values of connection header, the "Expires" is -1, and the function `function RawStrInternetToDateTime(var Value: string): TDateTime;` that internally uses `EncodeDate(Year, Month, Day);` can't work with the value '-1'.

Will I need to change directly on "exemple.exemple.ex", the "expires" value to some other datetime value?

Comment: Hard to decipher this.

Comment: You need to establish what -1 in the expires field means and treat it accordingly. For example if -1 means "never expires" then you could code the date as 31/12/9999

Comment: So, I need to change this directly on server? And I think its "never expires".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.borlandtalk.com/indy-rawstrinternettodatetime-parsedayofmonth-range-error-vt105516.html), Indy versions < 10 don't process "-1" correctly. This is how Indy 10 handles the "Expires" field:

```
// RLebeau 01/23/2006 - IIS fix
lValue := Values['Expires']; {do not localize}
if IsNumeric(lValue) then
begin
    // This is happening when expires is an integer number in seconds
    LSecs := Sys.StrToInt(lValue);
    // RLebeau 01/23/2005 - IIS sometimes sends an 'Expires: -1' header
    if LSecs >= 0 then begin
        FExpires := Sys.Now + (LSecs / SecsPerDay);
    end else begin
        FExpires := 0.0;
    end;
end else
begin
    FExpires := GMTToLocalDateTime(lValue);
end;
```

As you can see, the value is set to 0 if it was <= 0 initially, so this is what you have to do manually if you're using an older version of Indy.

Comment: Thats what I have: `if StrToIntDef(Values['Expires'], -1) <> -1 then {do not localize}
    begin
      // This is happening when expires is an integer number in seconds
      LSecs := StrToInt(Values['Expires']); {do not localize}
      FExpires := Now +  (LSecs / SecsPerDay);
    end
    else
    begin
      FExpires := GMTToLocalDateTime(Values['Expires']); {do not localize}
    end;` I have to change it manually, so?  Thanks!